# Triangle inside a disk of radius equals to the perimeter of the triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Let's fix a triangle in the plane:

$\Delta=\{t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid t_1,t_2,t_3 \ge 0 \quad \land \quad t_1+t_2+t_3=1\}$

of vertices $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and an open disk:

$D=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \|x-x_0\|<r\}$

of radius $r>0$ and center $x_0 \in \Delta$.

Suppose that the perimeter of $\Delta$ is inferior to $2r$, namely:

$\|x_2-x_1\|+\|x_3-x_2\|+\|x_1-x_3\|<2r$.

I want to show that $\Delta \subseteq D$.

Here is my attempt:

$x_0 \in \Delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad x_0=t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3$,

with $t_1+t_2+t_3=1$ and $t_1,t_2,t_3 \ge 0$ (and so $t_1,t_2,t_3 \in [0,1]$).

We have $\|x_1-x_0\|=\|x_1-t_1x_1-t_2x_2-t_3x_3\|=\|(1-t_1)x_1-t_2x_2-t_3x_3\|=$

$=\|(t_2+t_3)x_1-t_2x_2-t_3x_3\| \le t_2\|x_1-x_2\|+t_3\|x_1-x_3\| \le$

$\le \|x_1-x_2\|+\|x_1-x_3\|<2r-\|x_3-x_2\|$.

Here I get stuck. If I could show that $\|x_1-x_0\|<r$ (and similarly $\|x_2-x_0\|<r,\|x_3-x_0\|<r$), then I could easily show that $\Delta \subseteq D$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that from $\|x_2-x_1\|+\|x_3-x_2\|+\|x_1-x_3\|<2r$ follows that
$$\max\{\|x_2-x_1\|,\|x_3-x_2\|,\|x_1-x_3\|\} < r.$$
Indeed, if e.g. $\|x_2-x_1\| \ge r$ then by triangle inequality we would get
$$r \le \|x_2-x_1\| \le \|x_2-x_3\|+ \|x_1-x_3\|$$
so altogether $\|x_2-x_1\| +\|x_2-x_3\|+ \|x_1-x_3\| \ge 2r$ which is a contradiction.

Write $x_0 = t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3$ so
\begin{align}
\|x_0-x_1\| &= \|t_1x_1 + t_2x_2+t_3x_3 -(t_1 + t_2+t_3)x_1\|\\
&\le t_2\|x_2-x_1\| + t_3\|x_3-x_1\|\\
&\le (t_1+t_2)\max\{\|x_2-x_1\|,\|x_3-x_2\|,\|x_1-x_3\|\}\\
&< r
\end{align}
so $x_1 \in B(x_0,r)$. Similarly we show that $x_2,x_3 \in B(x_0,r)$ so $B(x_0,r)$ contains the convex set $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$. Since the open ball $B(x_0,r)$ is a convex set, we conclude that it also contains the convex hull of $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ which is $\Delta$.

Comment: Thank you! The central point is the fact that $\max\{\|x_2-x_1\|,\|x_3-x_2\|,\|x_1-x_3\|\}<r$.